# Time Format Naming

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

Does anyone know if there are names for certain types of formatting of time's and dates like

```
h:m:s:ms

xh xm xs xms
```

etc?

I would like some way to describe these different formats for an enumeration to pass to a formatter.